# Xcode8.3 iOS10 Copy Files from Package to App Directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xcode8

In Xcode8.3 for iOS10  I am trying to copy files from Package Directory to Apps dedicated directory.  This worked great up to iOS6 but not on iOS8 and up.

i is index files in a for loop:

```
NSString* currentfilename = [[dbfileManager directoryContentsAtPath: bundleFolderPath] objectAtIndex:i];
NSString*s =[NSString stringWithFormat:@".db"];
//NSLog(@"getAllMapDBFileNames db file exist=%@",s);
    if ([currentfilename rangeOfString:s].location != NSNotFound){
        NSString *tmpfilename=[[[currentfilename stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@" "] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".db" withString:@""] capitalizedString];
        NSString *strdestination = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", bundleFolderPath,currentfilename];
        NSLog(@"DOES Exist! = %@",tmpfilename);
        NSLog(@"strdestination = %@",strdestination);
        NSString *toPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", dbappFolderPath,currentfilename];
        NSLog(@"toPath = %@",toPath);
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager]copyItemAtPath:strdestination toPath:toPath error:NULL]; //&Error
  }
```

Why iOS 8 and up blocking this?

Comment: What are the values you are getting on the console ? And did you check error pointer ?

Comment: @MidhunMP I will check and let you know..

Answer (score 0):

This code actual works! I am not sure if Xcode 8.3 has file size limitation.